# How can I implement two functions with same name with in one class in C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have two void functions with the same name, but different parameters. and, Code is not compiling. I am using eclipse for compiling.

Note: Here I was looking for override function. Problem is solved.

Comment: Please post the code instead of describing it.

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what you are doing wrong, if you don't show the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I implement two functions with same name with in one class in
>   C?

C++ has classes not C.

Use [method/function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading):

```
class MyClass
{
   void method1(int x) {}
   void method1(int x, int y) {}

   void method2(int x) const {}
   void method2(int x) {}

   void method3(int x) {};
   void method3(int x, int y = 1) {}; // ERROR ambiguity! when .method3(1)
};
```

Notice, everything is the same but the signature of parameters or qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks. It does make sense now.